# There is lock on the table which persists the disconnection

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2012

I have a very small table in my database with only one row in it. When I do select statement on it, my query always times out. I have tried following things:

- Conecting/disconnecting from the database server
- doing select * from table(nolock)- which works fine and also proves that there is some lock on the table

However, How can I remove the lock from the table and how can I know what is holding the table captive? Also, I am not sure how does this lock survive the disconnection from the database server?

Comment: (unlock) is NOT a valid query hint. You mean to say NOLOCK. The lock is not from your connection but another connection. There is another connection somewhere that has the table locked.

Comment: Yes, it is nolock.  I am sorry for the confusion. Also, yes there was another connection from my code which was open. Thank you so much for the hint.

Comment: Cool glad you found it.